# Microsoft Event Graph API India dateTime timeZone issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an Event through Microsoft Graph API but getting datetime and timezone issue

What I am sending in the body.

```
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-08-25T09:52:00",
    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-08-25T09:58:00",
    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
  }
```

What I am getting in the response

```
"start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-09-01T09:52:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-09-01T09:58:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
    }
```

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I gave a try with Microsoft Graph explorer and it works for me without any issue. Alternately you can check with POSTMAN.

Here's my request:  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2019-09-13T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2019-09-13T14:00:00",
      "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
  }

Here's my response: "start": {
        "dateTime": "2019-09-13T12:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2019-09-13T14:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
    }

Comment: @SujeetKumar If you were able to resolve the issue, could you share your solution? I have the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: @nam I just answered, Please check the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

**I resolved it by sending payload like below**

```
url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events',


 headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'SdkVersion': 'postman-graph/v1.0',
        'outlook.timezone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
    },

    body: {
        subject: json.w_title,
        allowNewTimeProposals: true,
        isOnlineMeeting: true,
        onlineMeetingProvider: "teamsForBusiness",
        body: {
            "contentType": "HTML",
            "content": "Online Webinar"
        },
        start: {
            "dateTime": "2020-08-25T09:52:00",
            "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
        },
        end: {
            "dateTime": "2020-08-25T09:58:00",
            "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
        },
        location: {
            "displayName": "Bokaro Jharkhand"
        }
    }
```